# mysql select records with sum greater than specific number

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select records based on time(in second) listed in a MySQL database table, with a single query (no store procedures). The record set should contain all records where the sum total time equals or if needed exceeds a specific time. (Example, if i want get 4 random record where time(secound) sum is lessthen 30 second)

Table :

```
+----+-------+
| id | times |
+----+-------+
|  1 |      8|
|  2 |     20|
|  3 |      1|
|  4 |      3|
|  5 |      2|
|  6 |      6|
|  7 |      9|
|  9 |     15|
| 10 |     12|
| 11 |      8|
+----+-------+
```

Like i want 4 record randomly, it's doesn't matter whis come first
output will be like :
1

```
+----+-------+
| id | times |
+----+-------+
|  2 |     20|
|  3 |      1|
|  5 |      2|
|  6 |      6|
+----+-------+
SUM OF ALL TIME IS 29
```

2

```
+----+-------+
| id | times |
+----+-------+
|  3 |      1|
|  7 |      9|
| 10 |     12|
| 11 |      8|
+----+-------+
SUM OF ALL TIME IS 30
```

3

```
+----+-------+
| id | times |
+----+-------+
|  1 |      8|
|  5 |      2|
|  4 |      3|
|  9 |     15|
+----+-------+
SUM OF ALL TIME IS 28
```

Something like that

Comment: *i want get 4 random record where time(secound) sum is lessthen 30 second* Select 4 rows with the least time (or none if the sum for them exceeds). In shown example this will be 1+2+3+6=12<30

Answer (score 0):

Extensive solution for strict sum:

```sql
SELECT t1.times, t2.times, t3.times, t4.times
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
JOIN test t3 ON t2.id < t3.id
JOIN test t4 ON t3.id < t4.id
WHERE t1.times + t2.times + t3.times + t4.times = 30;
```

| times | times | times | times |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 8 | 1 | 6 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 15 | 12 |
| 8 | 1 | 9 | 12 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 |
| 8 | 2 | 12 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 | 12 | 8 |
| 1 | 6 | 15 | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/avoxK5Qw)

Comment: Thanks @Akina it's quite helpful, but every time i need one record and order must be randomlly.

Comment: @vipul.technomads Add `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. https://dbfiddle.uk/B4UZ6wmE

Comment: Yes i did already it's took a long time, like 10 to 12 second so it's not ideal

Comment: @vipul.technomads NP-tasks are not ideal for to be solved on the DBMS side at all..

Comment: But Thanks @Akina, i got solution for it. Thnaks for your help :)